# How can i automate using different values for profile and debug modes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, release

I have some some values which i need to change when i am releasing my app. I believe that, there is a better solution for this.

```
class MyModeRelatedVariables {
  get url => mode == Mode.Profile ? "ap.server.com" : "api.dev.server.com";
}
```

I use this script for releasing ios:

```
flutter clean \
        && rm ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock \
        && rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace \
        && flutter build ios --release --dart-define=MY_APP_ENV=prod
```